# thingsboard 1.4 can not start with error : Table not found: audit_log

Tags: thingsboard

I installed thingsboard 1.4.0 with PostgreSQL DB by following official document, but it can not start and the following is the starting log:

```
2018-03-16 11:24:09.875  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core 
{5.0.11.Final}
2018-03-16 11:24:09.882  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties 
not found
2018-03-16 11:24:09.892  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name 
: javassist
2018-03-16 11:24:10.138  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons 
Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-03-16 11:24:12.406  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-03-16 11:24:12.808  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual 
LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-03-16 11:24:12.810  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration 
[java.util.UUID] overrides previous : 
org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@50a44416
2018-03-16 11:24:15.261  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator         : HHH000229: Running schema 
validator
2018-03-16 11:24:15.443  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: 
audit_log
2018-03-16 11:24:15.446  INFO 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: 
audit_log
2018-03-16 11:24:15.464 ERROR 18818 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. 
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'thingsboardSecurityConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restAuthenticationProvider'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'restAuthenticationProvider' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/home/cloudadmin/thingsboard/application/target/thingsboard-1.4.0- 
SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-
```

The thingsboard server is on ubuntu16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [run the installation script](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux/#run-installation-script)?

> sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh